# Laravel: Base table or view not found: 1146 La Table 'database.migrations'

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was creating an application on Laravel. At some point of time, I had to reinstall my WAMP server. Now I installed it again and created the same database. When I tried to migrate everything again using the command `php artisan migrate`, I got the following errors.

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 La table 'learning.migrations' n'exists pas (SQL: create table 'migrations' ('migration' varchar(255) not null, 'batch' int null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)
```

and

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:1146 La table 'learning.migrations' n'existe pas
```

and

```
migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--force] [--path["..."]] [--package[="..."]] [--pretend] [--seed]
```

What might be the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: Try these two commands, to see if `artisan` and `composer` work first, `$ php artisan env` and `$ composer dumpautoload`

Comment: `Current application environment: production`

Second one:

'Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "TablePrograms" was found in both -------'

Comment: (-----) means It's comparing two migration files. I don't wanna type that big section.

Comment: The problem is that the table `migrations` in database `learning` is not created, and the cause is related either to database config or migrations. You can check if database `learning` exists, the database config for `production` is `learning`.

Comment: The Database is existing. How can I check the Database config for the Production?

Comment: Look up: `app/config/database.php`, key `mysql => array()`

Comment: `'mysql' => array(
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => 'localhost',
   'database'  => 'learning',
   'username'  => 'root',
   'password'  => '',
   'charset'   => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix'    => '',
  ),`

Comment: is database `learning` empty? I mean by the state of database after creating through this, `CREATE DATABASE learning;`

Comment: Yeah, the database is empty. No table at all. I created it directly from phpmyadmin panel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was from the wamp reinstall. When I reinstalled the wamp server, in the MySQL folder, there was an old file with the database name and everything (this was because I had not deleted the DB before reinstalling WAMP). So all you gotta do is go to your MySQL installation folder, in my case: `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data` and delete the folder with the old db name. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

In your phpMyAdmin:  create the database.

In your command console:

1) In your proyect folder execute: php artisan migrate:install
This will create the table "migrations" in your database

2) Then execute:  php artisan migrate